# How to dynamically change datatables without editor functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I need some help, I’ve been trying to solve this problem for ever and I cannot figure it out. I have a webpage that has two tables adjacent to each other, each table row has three divisions, first  the name of an employee, then their salary and in the final division a button. By pressing the button, you remove the employee’s row from their current table, and it is moved to the other one, mimicking moving them between departments.
I had this working all well and good but then I tried to implement a system where you can sort each table either alphabetically or by salary. I did this using the datatables plugin. This worked, but whenever I sort by either one, it resets the table, meaning that all the rows that had been moved are still in their new table, but now there are duplicate copies in the original.

I figured what was happening is that the datatable is created when the page loads, and when sorting the datatable adds back in all the original rows. I realise I could probably fix the problem by having it so that every time I click on the sort feature, I use JavaScript to recheck the table and remove rows that have been added, but this solution seems too hacky, and there must be a more elegant solution, as also this might get slow with larger number of rows.

If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful. My code is below.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#righttable').DataTable( {
        "bFilter": false
    } );
} );

$('table').on('click', 'button', function() {
    if ($(this).closest('tbody').attr('id')=='Left') {
      let name = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();
      let index = selected_team.indexOf(name);
      console.log(name, index);
      selected_team.splice(index, 1);
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      $('#righttable').append('<tr><td><a class="article-title" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+name+'</a></td>'+'<td>'+stats[name][0]+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-success">+</button></td></tr>');
    }
    if ($(this).closest('tbody').attr('id')=='Right') {
      let name = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      $('#lefttable').append('<tr><td><a class="article-title" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+name+'</a></td>'+'<td>'+stats[name][0]+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger">-</button></td></tr>');
      selected_team.push(name);
    }
});
```

HTML (abridged):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id='lefttable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="Left">
                    {%for player in players%}
                        {%if player in team%}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a class="article-title" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{player}}</a></td>
                                <td>{{hstats[player][0]}}</td>
                                <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {%endif%}
                    {%endfor%}


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

        <div class='col-sm-5 table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar'>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id='righttable'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="Right">
                     {%for player in players%}
                        {%if player not in team%}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a class="article-title" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{player}}</a></td>
                                <td>{{hstats[player][0]}}</td>
                                <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-success">+</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {%endif%}
                    {%endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Datatables is in charge of rendering these tables now, you cant be chopping and changing this state without informing datatables. Your mechanism for this move should be to inform datatables and ask *it* to update. You can use these functions to alter the data - https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()